# Prevent MySQL login with empty password

Tags: mysql, security

I created a new user with:

```
CREATE USER 'foobar'@'%';
```

...and I was rather disturbed to find that this user was allowed to log in, using an empty password!

```
> select host, user, authentication_string from mysql.user where user = 'foobar';
+------+--------+-----------------------+
| host | user   | authentication_string |
+------+--------+-----------------------+
| %    | foobar |                       |
+------+--------+-----------------------+
```

- How can I prevent users logging in with empty passwords?
- Alternatively, is there a way to create a user with some sort of invalid password so they cannot login until their password is updated?

Comment: See MySQL reference & Syntax to create users. You can provide a password hash there. You could go and post there a random hash or even just a string as "invalid password". https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`CREATE USER 'username'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password' PASSWORD EXPIRE;`

Which will create a password that can only be used once and will require the user to choose a new password at login.

Suggest if you are creating and issuing passwords you use a random generator to create an initial random password and then share it securely.

Comment: Otherwise a common practice is to set the password hash (not the password - you can also set the hash directly) as '0' or 'A' or some value that won't even match the output of the hash algorithm. That way they have an invalid password that can't be used until it is changed.